# laravel sentry and login with 2 different computers

Tags: authentication, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I'm using sentry for many reasons one of them is this feature that it log out a user while login from 2 different computer
so I m using local host how can I activate this feature? 
or make sure that is active right now?

Comment: Can you test it in two different browsers? That's what I usually do.

Comment: @Kai Thanks . I registered in firefox and then opened the ie and register again . what should be happened? both of them registered me. for using this feature of sentry I should just register user with sentry? just do that?  **`try{ $user=Sentry::register(array(
                'username'=>Input::get('username'),
                'password'=>Input::get('password'),
                'email'=>Input::get('email')
            ));  
        }`**

Answer (score 0):

You need two computer to test `Login from 2 different computer`.

First computer need to create a web-server and second computer access the first computer web-server(localhost). And now you can test your `Login from 2 different computer`.

If you don't know how to access your localhost from another computer you can see at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018955/how-to-access-my-localhost-from-another-pc-in-lan).

**Note** : This is my way. There are many others way to test `Login from 2 different computer`. You can find much more.